# Installation of SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a doubt regarding SSRS installation. I see two methods on the web.However I am not sure if both lead to same solution.

1)Install SSRS via installer OF SIZE 105 mb.

2)Install Visual Studio Community, then SSDT, which in turn installs SSRS, and post this  install templates via VS extensions.

My question is whether both these methods lead to the same result? If not which is the correct one?

The requirement in m organisation is to develop SSRS reports using TSQL DYNAMIC QUERIES,FUNCTIONS,AND STORED PROCEDURES.

SERVER :SQL SERVER 2019 DEVELOPER EDITION

Answer (score 2):

I think you are possibly confusing two different but related items. The first is the installation, which you absolutely should use the installer for. Full installation instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

The second item is about creating and publishing content. Generally you do this via SSDT or the BI Components of Visual Studio (or just knock up the XML in a text editor of your choice if you feel like a challenge). Once you have created your reports you can then publish them to SSRS via Visual Studio or take the RDL file and publish it manually. There is a brief [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15) on how to do this in MS Docs.

The most important difference between these two items though is that even if you installed SSDT/Visual Studio and have created your reports, unless you have actually got somewhere to host them (i.e. by installing SSRS on a server or within Power BI Service) then you cannot share them or access them other than from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation. So as I understand, I need not have SSRS installed unless I have to publish reports somewhere, so that others can view .But having SSDT+VS Community helps me to create and view my reports on my own. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @aravindnk that is correct.